# Dart random unique numbers

Tags: flutter, dart

I need help! am creating an app in flutter where I need 8 unique ranodm numbers. So how can I create a list of 8 random numbers which are all unique in Dart? If I go through a for loop using the random class and then append it to a list there is still the chance of repeating numbers. Anybody can help?

Comment: random from 0 to infinity?

Comment: random from 0 to specified list.length( in my case  25 e.g.)

Comment: use [shuffle](http://localhost/flutter/doc-1.10.15/flutter/dart-core/List/shuffle.html)

Comment: to use shuffle, I need an existing list. But I want to create a list with random numbers

Comment: `print([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]..shuffle())`

Comment: `print((List<int>.generate(25, (i) => i)..shuffle()).take(8));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the random number is already existing in the list before adding it. I created an example, I hope it helps you.

In this example, I am trying to generate 8 completely unique random numbers between 0 and 8. You can change these numbers as you want it will not affect the code (But make sure the random range is equal or bigger than the list length you want, or the code will break).

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  List<int> randomNumbers = [];
  
  //While the length of the list is smaller than 8 (the length I want),
  //keep trying to add unique random numbers.
  while(randomNumbers.length < 8){
    
    //Get a random number between 0 and 8 (Edit this numbers as you want) 
    //from the method we created below at the bottom.
    int randomNum = randomInt(0,8);
    
    //Check if the random number is already existing in the list.
    bool condition = randomNumbers.where((number) => number == randomNum).toList().isEmpty;
    
    //If the number is not existing, add the number to the list.
    //Else do nothing (repeat the while loop to find another number).
    if(condition){
     randomNumbers.add(randomNum);
    }
  }
  
  print(randomNumbers);
}

// A method to get a random integer. Max and min are inclusive.
int randomInt(int min, int max) {
    return Random().nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
}
```

The output will be completely unique 8 numbers such as : `[0, 1, 5, 2, 4, 6, 3, 8]`.